# Django filter not working with lookup object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the next code using Django Rest Framework

```
        images = ImageUploaded.objects.filter(offer__end_date > date.today())
```

However, I got the next error:

> global name 'offer__end_date' is not defined

The ImageUploaded model is the next:

```
class ImageUploaded(models.Model):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, related_name='images', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    image = models.ImageField("Uploaded image")
```

And the offer model is:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
ARGENTINA = 'ARG'
URUGUAY = 'URG'
COUNTRIES = (
    (ARGENTINA, 'Argentina'),
    (URUGUAY, 'Uruguay')
)

name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
description = models.TextField()
created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
end_date = models.DateField()
available = models.IntegerField()
current = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Try `images = ImageUploaded.objects.filter(offer__end_date__gt=date.today())`

Comment: @ABDULNIYASPM thank you so much for your quick answer, I just updated the code and it fixed the error, but now I got the next error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'offer'